# Passing the response of one API call to another API as a parameter in same file in React

Tags: reactjs

I am learing react and I am stuck in my project. I have two APIs. I fetch cookie  from one API and I want to use that cookie as a parameter in another API and both API is called in the same file i.e index.js. How to do this?

Comment: Make the call. When it's done make the other call. What's the specific issue?

Comment: Could you share your code? It get's easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about promises. Based on your problem, you already know that API calls are asynchronous. You control async functions by "forcing" them to wait and return their response before proceeding to the next line of code. A promise is an object you use as a wrapper for your API that does this for you. Here's a basic example:

```
const apiPromise = () => new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
  const apiData = myApiCallForCookies()
  resolve(apiData)
})

apiPromise().then(cookies => nextApiCall(cookies))
```

If you are confused by the syntax with things like `.then`, MDN docs are your friend.